# Sort a iList bevor i process them

Tags: vb.net, list

I have a problem in Vb.net. 
After reading a Json file from an XML file into an iList, I want to sort the data there before I process it further. But the XML file has no headline.

Here ist the File:

```
["000100000000000000000000;22:03:26.991;192.168.5.88;0001;0;2019-11-18;22:04:39",
"E28011700000020CFF178201;22:04:11.070;192.168.5.88;0001;0;2019-11-18;22:04:39",
"E28011700000020CFF178201;22:05:11.252;192.168.5.88;0001;0;2019-11-18;22:13:10",
"E28011700000020CFF178201;22:13:11.920;192.168.5.88;0001;0;2019-11-18;22:13:15",
"E28011700000020CFF178201;22:13:41.924;192.168.5.88;0001;0;2019-11-18;22:13:46",
"E28011700000020CFF178201;22:14:12.249;192.168.5.88;0001;0;2019-11-18;22:14:18",
"E28011700000020CFF178201;22:14:42.562;192.168.5.88;0001;0;2019-11-18;22:14:44",
"E28011700000020CFF178201;22:15:12.729;192.168.5.88;0001;0;2019-11-18;22:15:15"]
```

and here is the code for processing the data

```
   Dim myList As IList
    Dim File As String =  Filename()
        Dim t As String = JsonString(File)
        myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of String))(t)
        For Each item In myList
            Dim data() As String = item.ToString.Split(";")
            .....
        Next
```

I want to sort the data descending by time (2nd column) before I process them.

Comment: delete ``c#`` tag from your post

Comment: It would be better to deserialize (or convert after deserialization) to a class object, to auto-convert the date and time strings to TimeSpan and DateTimeOffset properties, so you can then order the `List(Of class)` objects correctly.

Comment: I think that's a good idea. Thanks!